# Show custom option on "My Downloadable Products" page in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to display selected custom option on "MY Downloadable products" page. How to fetch it? 
Please help

Comment: more info please?  What information, from which model?

Comment: I have store for book which user can download i.e Magento's Downloadable Products. I am giving an options (EPUB, PDF, TEST) format to download. I need the selected option to show on "My downloadable products" page  for My account Section.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that downloadable products already provides for different file types. In the product's "Downloadable Information" tab upload files for each of your types (EPUB, PDF, etc.) and set "Links can be purchased separately" to "No". When a customer selects one to purchase they get a link in their "My downloadable products" section for just that file.

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute in the back end admin catalog for the product.

Display the attribute by creating a template for the field which you then need to define a containing block for it in a layout.xml file.